# MongoDB Sharding - why my data isn't being distributed on all shards?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I created a MongoDB Cluster with 3 shards, each shards contain 3 `mongod-processes`. My Cluster also contains 3 `mongos` and 3 `config servers`

In the connection string I put the 3 `mongos`

```
mongodb://user:pass@mongos1:27017,mongos2:27017,mongos3:27017/mydatabase
```

In the picture you can see that `dbShard_2` has 1.19GB of data while the others are almost empty with only 4KB. But on the charts you can see that there is also read/write operation on all shards. Is everything fine or did I have made some wrong configurations? shall I worry?

I left the Cloud Manager do the whole configuration for me, I didn't set these by myself manually.

Here you can check my sharding status

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus();
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("XXXXX")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "dbShard_0",  "host" : "dbShard_0/dbnode-0.x-app.com:27000,dbnode-1.x-app.com:27000,dbnode-2.x-app.com:27000" }
        {  "_id" : "dbShard_1",  "host" : "dbShard_1/dbnode-0.x-app.com:27001,dbnode-2.x-app.com:27001,dbnode-2.x-app.com:27002" }
        {  "_id" : "dbShard_2",  "host" : "dbShard_2/dbnode-0.x-app.com:27002,dbnode-1.x-app.com:27001,dbnode-2.x-app.com:27003" }
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "mydatabase-staging",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "dbShard_2" }
        {  "_id" : "mydatabase",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "dbShard_2" }
        {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "dbShard_0" }
```

[Cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G4zK.png)

Comment: Well there could be many reasons. 1) Incorrect choice of shard key. 2) your database/collection is not sharded. 3) if non of above is true, give some time to your cluster, it should balance itself.

Comment: how can I check 1.2.3 ? and if one or some are true, is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @Saleem check my edit

Comment: @Saleem I think because partitioned is set to false

Comment: Good work. Keep digging and you'll make it. This is THE best way to learn.

Comment: @Saleem yeah I just need to add the chunks/keys https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#enable-sharding-for-a-database